# Creating an Android app similar to an iOS one that uses coredata

Tags: android, ios, core-data, tableview

I'm new to android and android development. I'm trying to make an app similar to one that I made for iOS which uses coredata to manage a list of objects in a tableview. Could you give me some reference points for me to look up because I don't even know where to start. What would be the android "translation" for tableview, coredata and entity? Any links to any kind of documentation or tutorials would be a lot of help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableView is called [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) in Android.

[ListView Tutorial.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

CoreData is called [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) [Database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html) in Android.

Entity is called Table in Android (which is done using SQL code programmatically, not same as Xcode way as UI to create Entities and Coredata).

[SQLite Database Tutorial.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Note: [Android Training](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) from Google is a good start if you are new in Android Development.

Comment: CoreData and SQLite are not the same thing even when both are used to save data.